# Is there a way to capture visitor's IP addresses and link clicked via AMPScript in a Marketing Cloud "Cloud Page"?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

In Marketing Cloud, Cloud Pages, is there a way to be able to capture a visiting user's IP address, device, link clicked, and so on, via AMPScript or SSJS?  I know this is possible when working with normal websites via server side code.  Curious about Cloud Pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IP as an example is easy with SSJS, very hard with AMPScript.
SSJS:

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1"); 
var ip = Platform.Request.ClientIP(); 
Variable.SetValue("ip",ip);
</script>
%%=v(@ip)=%%
```

the full documentation for what you are looking for is here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformHTTPPropertyFunctions.htm